# How to style drop down list for Ajax / jQuery results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm using ajax and jquery UI to search and select in the input field. How can I style the drop down thing to not to show me `<ul>` bullets and also have a white background? I have been trying to target the search field using ID but it changes the input box and not the drop down box. I'm attaching the screenshot here.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone like me is struggling with jQuery UI stylying for Ajax calls, here is bootstrap code which I'm copy pasting from a blog and it is working perfectly for me.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;   
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;
    }

.ui-menu-item > a.ui-corner-all {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555555;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.ui-state-hover, .ui-state-active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #0088cc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    background-image: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A css solution

change the list style type on you li tags to `none`. and add a white background to your ul tag

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none
}

ul {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Option</li>
  </ul
```